# Proposal for math teaching/pedagogy SE needs an influx of new people

Tags: discussion, area51

Many people are unaware that Stackexchange allows users to create their own sites using a model similar to the question/answer system used on their main sites. Someone creates a proposal, others write down some question titles, and finally all users vote to see which questions are the best. One such proposal is [Math Teaching and Pedagogy](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64216/mathematics-learning-studying-and-education).

The site moves forward when 40 questions have 10 votes each. But there's a catch: each person gets just five votes. So a LOT of people have to vote (well, 80 people).

The math teaching/pedagogy proposal needs less than 80 votes from other users. Once it gets them, people have a chance to sign up using their email for a private beta, where you try to answer or ask 10 questions to give the new site momentum. Once 200 people sign up, the site is created.

Please take the time to consider this proposal. As of now, <8 or 9 academia.SE people have voted there, so you would be a new population who cares about education and who can influence the future of the site.

Consider checking it out; casting your votes brings you no obligations.

Here's the link:http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64216/mathematics-learning-studying-and-education

Comment: A little bit confused. 10 votes already counts or the number of upvotes must be greater than 10? I saw many example questions has count 10.

Comment: Yeah, 10 votes already counts.